# PHP Calculation - percentage of input

Tags: php

I have a script that calculates the percentage of an input.

```
$total_debt = "16,000";
$debt_written_off_percentage = 70;
$debt_written_off = ($debt_written_off_percentage / 100) * $total_debt;

$reduced_debt_percentage = 30;
$reduced_debt = ($reduced_debt_percentage / 100) * $total_debt;

echo $total_debt;
echo '<br>';
echo $debt_written_off;
echo '<br>';
echo $reduced_debt;
echo '<br>';
exit();
```

When I run this script, I get the following output:

```
16,000
11.2
4.8
```

Why is it not:

```
16,000
11,200
4,800
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `error_reporting(-1)`, you'll get:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...

indicating that `$total_debt` is problematic.

---

**Solution**: Use a real number value, e.g.:

```
$total_debt = 16000;
// ...
```

---

Reference: [Integers](https://php.net/manual/language.types.integer.php), [Floating point numbers](https://php.net/manual/language.types.float.php) and for what it's worth [Type Juggling](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks so much, @Yoshi :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because your `$total_debt = "16,000";` is a string and when used it will be cast to `int` removing the comma. So use

```
$total_debt = 16000;
```

You have to format your output in order to fit your needs with:

```
function number_format ($number , $decimals = 0 , $dec_point = '.' , $thousands_sep = ',' ) {}
```

So you should replace with:

```
echo number_format($total_debt, 3, ",");
echo '<br>';
echo number_format($debt_written_off, 3, ",");
echo '<br>';
echo number_format($reduced_debt, 3, ",");
echo '<br>';
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Covert your `total_debt` **string to integer** first and then you can try your logic.

```
 <?php

    $total_debt = (int)16000;
    $debt_written_off_percentage = 70;
    $debt_written_off = ($debt_written_off_percentage / 100) * $total_debt;

    $reduced_debt_percentage = 30;
    $reduced_debt = ($reduced_debt_percentage / 100) * $total_debt;

    echo $total_debt;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $debt_written_off;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $reduced_debt;
    echo '<br>';
    exit();

  ?>
```